# Redirecting the stdout and stdin - Java

Tags: java, c++, debugging, io, freopen

While writing `c/c++` code it's pretty handy to use [freopen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/). Please see the following code snippet -

```
int main(){

 int n1, n2, result;

 freopen("input.txt", "rb", stdin);
 freopen("output.txt", "wb", sdtout);

 while(scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2)==2 && n1>0 &&n2>0){
  ...
  ...
  ...
  printf("%d\n", result);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

The use of `freopen()` in this way is very useful when we are trying to debug/test a small console application. We can put the sample input in **'input.txt'** file once and reuse them every time instead of giving the input manually in terminal/console. And similarly we can print the output in **'output.txt**' file.

Now I am looking foreword a similar type of solution in **java** so that I can redirect input and output to text file. My target is to simplify the small console/program debugging while manipulating with some data. Providing these data to terminal/console recurrently as input is somewhat cumbersome. Can anyone suggest some good tips for doing this?

Comment: WHat is wrong with do this on the command line with `java -cp ... MyClass < input.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For System.out

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("output-file.txt")));
```

For System.err

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new File("err_output-file.txt")));
```

For System.in

```
System.setIn(new FileInputStream(new File("input-file.txt")));
```

*to reset back to console

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
System.setIn(new FileInputStream(FileDescriptor.in));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can reassign the streams using [`System.setIn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream)) and [`System.setOut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)).

```
System.setIn(new FileInputStream(new File("input.txt")));
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("output.txt")));
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting data from a file rather than user input, you just have to change what you do when you construct your Scanner a little bit.

import java.io.*; for some classes, then do this:

```
try{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input_file_name.in"));
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then just use the scanner as normal and it will read from the file.

To write to a data file rather than standard out, you can do this to change the standard output to a data file:

```
try{
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("output_file_name.out"));
    PrintStream p = new PrintStream(f);
    System.setOut(p);
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

All operations with System.out.print() and System.out.println() will write to the the file.